# the usage of ''are being + <adjective> ''

Tags: gerunds

Is the following sentence natural?

> The qualities of robots are being predictable and precise.

In this sentence, can I use

> "are + being + <adjective>"?

Comment: I suppose it's "more or less" *natural*, but I think it would certainly be more *elegant* to go with *The qualities of robots are **predictability** and **precision***. I have to say that unqualified ***qualities*** doesn't seem like the best choice here. Better alternatives might be ***attributes*** or ***advantages***, depending on the intended nuance (I assume ***disadvantages*** isn't likely to be intended).

Answer (score 1):

You could say that, but because "are being" is such a familiar phrase as a continuous verb, the sentence as you've written it is likely to be confusing. I read it first with "predictable and precise" as the complement (and the verb as "are being", so implying a temporary, contingent, state).

Comment: I think you've nailed the *syntactic* problem. But on the *semantic* level I think it's fair to say OP's ***qualities*** is used in exactly the same way as, say, *The qualities of cars are being fuel-efficient and reliable*. Which doesn't really work for me even if I recast to *The qualities of cars are fuel-efficiency and reliability*. In such constructions, unqualified ***qualities*** implies ***defining qualities*** (which the specified attributes *aren't*). So I'd expect something like *The **most important qualities** of cars [today] are fuel-efficiency and reliability*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, if you mean that they are as specified *in this very moment*, but in general they're different. If use the present simple tense («The qualities of robots are very predictable and precise»), you're stating something that is valid in general, as a rule.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood OP's text. It's not that the qualities themselves are *predictable, precise* (i.e. - that one could easily guess what those qualities might be, and easily define them with great precision). It's that the *robots themselves* are *predictable, precise* (these are attributes of the robots, not of the qualities).

Comment: @FumbleFingers your comment to the question and your alternative version of the sentence lead to this interpretation. Then, shouldn't there be a colon between "are" and "being"? I mean, shouldn't the sentence be: «The qualities of robots are **:** being predictable and precise.»?

Comment: Nah. There's nothing inherently *wrong* with introducing a colon, but it would be a bit "pretentious" in many contexts. Bear in mind the colon is only justifiable insofar as it's an orthographic representation of a long drawn-out pause (before portentously delivering the *list* to follow, which in this case would be a bit short/trivial to carry the weight of such a drum-roll introduction). I'm sure you can imagine the statement being made with no detectable pause after the word ***are***, which I personally think is a far more likely delivery.

Comment: ...besides which, as soon as you introduce the colon/pause, it's suddenly essential that there should be *at least two* clearly-identifiable items in the list that follows. You'd have to unpick OP's deletion, and say *The qualities of robots are: being predictable and **being** precise*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm convinced by your explanation, but I'm waiting for a clarification from the original poster.